# How to create a Stored Procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was creating a Stored Procedure for validation based on not allowing special characters in LeaveTypeText, for my project that I am learning now. And I want LeaveTypeText to not allow duplicate values and update LeaveTypeKey based on LeaveTypeText by removing space in between two characters.

How can I correct this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PreSaveAnd_AfterSave_Validation] (
    @FBFormId INT
    ,@PkId INT
    ,@TF_ProjectId INT
    ,@UserDetails NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@IsPostSave BIT
    ,@ContactId INT
    ,@Who NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@RoleId INT
    ,@Culture NVARCHAR(200)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @GlobalDateFormatCode INT
    DECLARE @ErrorMsg NVARCHAR(Max)

    SELECT @GlobalDateFormatCode = dbo.TF_FN_GetCurrentDateFormat()

    IF ISNULL(@IsPostSave, 0) = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ParaMeterTable TABLE (
            Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
            ,ParameterName NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ,ParameterValue NVARCHAR(MAX)
            )

        INSERT INTO @ParaMeterTable (
            ParameterName
            ,ParameterValue
            )
        SELECT LTRIM(LEFT(Value, CHARINDEX('=', Value, 0) - 1)) AS ParameterName
            ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Value, CHARINDEX('=', Value, 0) + 1, LEN(Value))) AS ParameterValue
        FROM dbo.TF_FN_Split(@UserDetails, '||')
        WHERE ISNULl(Value, '') <> ''

        --SELECT * FROM @ParaMeterTable
        DECLARE @LeaveTypeText NVARCHAR(1000)
        DECLARE @LeaveTypeKey NVARCHAR(1000)

        --SELECT @LeaveTypeText = ParameterValue
        --FROM @ParaMeterTable
        --WHERE ParameterName LIKE '@LeaveTypeText%'
        --select @LeaveTypeKey = LeaveTypeKey from DBO.Master_LeaveType_Sample
        --SELECT @LeaveTypeText
        SET @ErrorMsg = ' "Leave Type Key" field does not allow Special characters '

        --Validate Here
        IF EXISTS (@LeaveTypeKey like '%$%')
        BEGIN
            SELECT 0 AS IsValid
                ,@ErrorMsg AS [ErrorMessage]
        END

        IF (ISNULL(@ErrorMsg, '') != '')
        BEGIN
            SELECT 0 AS IsValid
                ,@ErrorMsg AS [ErrorMessage]
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT 1 IsValid
                ,dbo.TF_FN_GetCultureMessage('TF_DB_Success', @ContactId, @Who, @RoleId, @Culture) AS [ErrorMessage]
        END
    END
    ELSE IF ISNULL(@IsPostSave, 0) = 1
    BEGIN
        -- Post Save Logic
        UPDATE DBO.Master_LeaveType_Sample
        SET LeaveTypeKey = Replace(ParameterValue, ' ', '')
        FROM DBO.Master_LeaveType_Sample
        WHERE LeaveTypeText = ParameterValue

        SELECT 1 IsValid
            ,dbo.TF_FN_GetCultureMessage('TF_DB_Success', @ContactId, @Who, @RoleId, @Culture) AS [ErrorMessage]
    END
END
```

Comment: This seems more appropriate for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Use `RAISERROR` or `THROW` to end execution in an error; use `RETURN` if you're just done processing.

Comment: Although a review was requested in the question, I don't think this is seeking a code review. Rather the question author has some bugs/problems and would like suggestions at to what they are - in other words, this is not working code.